# How to "sanitize" api responses in redux?

Tags: javascript, rest, redux, reducers

I used "sanitize" because of lack of better word, "normalize" seems to be a little bit about different thing too.

I want to know what is the proper way of handling API responses in my app. I'm talking about a situation where there is a discrepancy between what app expects to be in redux-store to render properly and what is delivered by the backend.

For example, I have a reducer and an action:

```
const InitialState = {
  user: {
    id: -1,
    name: '',
    hobbies: [], // list of strings
    address: {
      city: '',
      country: '',
    }
  }
}

// in reducer
case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    user: payload.data, // replace default values with response from backend
  }
}
```

I'm expecting that response from backend will the type and shape of **InitialState.user**, but that can easily change especially in early stages of development making the app crash if not handled with a bunch of `if's`. For example, if backend changes `hobbies` field changes from array -> object:

```
hobbies: {
  count: 34,
  list: [...],
}
```

then the app will crash in places where until now I did:

```
user.hobbies.map(h => ...
```

the same would happen if tried to access `user.address.city` when backend "by mistake" would forget to deliver or has returned `address: null`.

I hope that's clear what bothers me. Until now I used [lodash defaultsDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#defaultsDeep) method like:

```
case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    user: defaultsDeep(payload.data, IntialState.user),
  }
}
```

but this protects me only from fields that were `undefined` in response, not from `null` instead of `Object` or `Arrays` instead of `Object` and so on.

I couldn't find any best practices on the internet so I'm hoping someone will guide me to good practices or present some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've handled this in the past: create an adapter class responsible for returning payloads in the shape you would expect, and have the rest of your app communicate with that class instead of the actual service.

The adapter class would call the actual API, and marshal the returned response into the required form for your app.

This is probably a good idea anyway, since this sort of decoupling would make it easier to mock your API calls.